# Looping Promise returning an undefined object

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I've created a function that is processing an array of TV shows, and I'm trying to get the watched progress for each of them in a new array.

I've tried with a `.map`, `.foreach`, a `for` loop, with `Promise.all`, but it's always returning `undefined` if I'm putting the `.then` outside my `.map` promise.

**What am I doing wrong?**

- I'm using the [Trakt.tv API](https://github.com/vankasteelj/trakt.tv).
- [API Information](https://trakt.docs.apiary.io/#reference/shows/watched-progress/get-show-watched-progress)

---

```
trakt.users.watched({
    username: profile.user.username,
    type: 'shows',
    extended: 'noseasons'
}).then(watchedshows => {
    if (!isEmpty(watchedshows)) {
        //get progress for all watched shows
        watchedshows.map(element => {
            return trakt.shows.progress.watched({
                id: element.show.ids.trakt,
                hidden: 'false',
                specials: 'false'
            }).then(episodeProgress => {
                //if theres a next episode and last watched date is less than a year (discard unwatch shows)
                if (episodeProgress.next_episode && (new Date() - new Date(episodeProgress.last_watched_at)) / 31536000000 < 1) {
                    return element.show.title + ' s' + zeroprefix(episodeProgress.next_episode.season) + 'e' + zeroprefix(episodeProgress.next_episode.number);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}).then(result => {
    console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: `.then` can only be called on a function that returns a promise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to *chain* the promises created from `watchedshows.map` with the final `.then(result`, else the `result` function will run before the promises above have been resolved. Try using `Promise.all` instead:

```
trakt.users.watched({
  username: profile.user.username,
  type: 'shows',
  extended: 'noseasons'
}).then(watchedshows => {
  if (isEmpty(watchedshows)) return;
  //get progress for all watched shows
  return Promise.all( watchedshows.map(element => {
    return trakt.shows.progress.watched({
      id: element.show.ids.trakt,
      hidden: 'false',
      specials: 'false'
    }).then(episodeProgress => {
      //if theres a next episode and last watched date is less than a year (discard unwatch shows)
      if (episodeProgress.next_episode && (new Date() - new Date(episodeProgress.last_watched_at)) / 31536000000 < 1) {
        return element.show.title + ' s' + zeroprefix(episodeProgress.next_episode.season) + 'e' + zeroprefix(episodeProgress.next_episode.number);
      }
    });
  }));
}).then(result => {
  console.log(result);
});
```

Comment: Wow working flawlessly ! Thank you so much, it has given me a better understanding of how promises are working.